# Could not get unknown property 'VERSION_NAME' for project ':k4l-video-trimmer' of type org.gradle.api.Project

Tags: android

After importing "k4l-video-trimmer" library am getting this error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Dattatray\Studio Work Space\Box App Resource\BoxApp\mavenpush.gradle' line: 5
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

  > Could not get unknown property 'VERSION_NAME' for project ':k4l-video-trimmer' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: found solution VERTION_NAME was missing application lavel build.gradle

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you add in your app build.gradle:

```
project.ext {
    VERSION_NAME = '1.1.3-SNAPSHOT'
}
```